# Break e Continue em forEach Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

Como dar um `break` ou um `continue` em uma iteração utilizando `forEach`, no exemplo abaixo, conseguiria aproveitar o mesmo `forEach` para execução da validação?

```
List<Contratos> contratos= /* populando contratos*/;
contratos.forEach(numero ->{

    if( /* condicao de salvamento*/){
       /* Adiciona a lista para salvar*/
    }
    if(/* condicao de validação*/ ){
        break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Veja se é isso https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23308193/break-or-return-from-java-8-stream-foreach

Comment: Você não pode mudar a pergunta. Você perguntou como dar um `break`, aí eu respondi que não tem como dar, aí você mudou a pergunta dizendo que sabe que não tem como dar, mas se a pergunta inicial era como dar foi com minha resposta que aprendeu que não tem como dar, portanto minha resposta respondeu sua pergunta e aí você quis fazer outra pergunta. Mesmo a nova, eu ainda respondi o que pode fazer e o que não deve fazer e obviamente não vou mostrar o que não deve fazer. Qq solução q seja usar este método se precisa de um `break` está errada,apesar de funcionar:https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQiXB.jpg

Comment: E mesmo na nova pergunta eu respondi também: `Sei que não existe o break no forEach, gostaria de saber qual seria a forma mais eficiente de codificar isso?`Minha resposta foi não usar este método e usar o `for` normal. Não tem como ser mais eficiente que isso. Alias se eficiência é importante isto deveria ser feito mesmo se não precisasse do `break`. Tudo isto está na minha resposta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não existe break e continue em stream, já que seu objetivo principal é executar iterações em paralelo, portando dar um "break" ou um "continue" seria extremamente ineficiente e muito provavelmente resultaria em retornos errôneos, afinal ele não conseguiria comunicar as threads em paralelo e em momentos diferentes que deveriam "continuar" ou "parar" a execução.
No exemplo dado o que poderia ser feito seria um filter para remover o numero indesejado, e executar posteriormente o foreach executando o que deveria ser executado, mas com o item indesejado já removido da lista.

`numeros.stream().filter( e -> e!= 4).forEach(numero ->{/*seu codigo*/ } );`

Como não é possivel fazer isto utilizando o foreach uma solução nada elegante sem substituir o lambda seria utilizar o throw exception:

```
List<Contratos> contratos= /* populando contratos*/;
try {
    contratos.forEach(numero ->{
        if( /* condicao de salvamento*/){
           /* Adiciona a lista para salvar*/
        }
        if(/* condicao de validação*/ ){
             throw new BreakException();
        }
    });
}catch (BreakException e) {
    // aqui vc saberia se foi dado o "break"
}
```

Ou simplesmente adicionar a validação no mesmo if do salvamento, executando todo o array, perdendo eficiência obviamente

Answer (score 6):

Bom, e para esse exemplo não faz muito sentido, mas vou considerar que seria usado em algum lugar que faça. E depende do exemplo concreto para dar uma solução adequada. De qualquer forma o `forEach()` quase sempre não é a solução adequada, e se precisa desse controle de fluxo provavelmente já está errando antes em escolher usar isso, ainda mais neste exemplo. Se é mais fácil fazer com o `for` pra que complicar e tornar o código mais lento?

Em geral o `Continue` é solucionado mudando o fluxo do código, sempre é possível fazer isso para evitar o `continue`, ainda que em alguns caso o código fique pior. Só poderia falar em um exemplo concreto.

O `break` é mais complicado e a solução é não fazer isso, apenas impedir que o código continue sendo executado por completo, ou seja, você troca o `break` pelo `continue` (não literalmente, apenas mudando o fluxo) e ele não encerra antes, apenas não executa mais nada em cada item, solução terrível, por isso faça do jeito correto e não use este método.

Existe a solução da exceção sendo lançada, mais é o pior uso de uma exceção que já vi na vida.

Claro que se precisa parar antes tem [outros métodos de Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) que pode fazer o que deseja.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).